# Changing applications id in android breaks app

Tags: java, android

I currently have a problem with my app where the default application id of my app is `com.example.app` in `build.gradle` which means it can not be uploaded to the play store but if I go and change the id to `com.xxx.app` it will upload to the store but when you run the app it no longer work properly the initial activity loads but none of it functionality works and clicking on certain buttons just causes a crash. I've made sure the package names and the manifest all match but if I use anything other then `com.example` it doesn't work.

Is there something I'm missing or another file somewhere that needs updating to the new id to get it to work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some details about the functionality which isn't working along with the stacktrace(s) for the crashes (or at least the exceptions that trigger them) and the activity name attributes ( <activity android:name="...") in the AndroidManifest.xml and the package names specified in the source files.

I guess some of the crashes are due uncaught ActivityNotFoundExceptions which probably occur because of the mismatched package names of the android components (activities, services, ...). If you change the applicationId in the manifest/build.gradle, the activities must still be referred using their java package name (probably com.example.app.* in your case) which matches the old applicationId - unless you have renamed the packages containing the activities.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the package name it should be both in `build gradle` and in `android manifest` (`AndroidManifest.xml`) for the part where it says

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxx.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

and in build gradle

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.app"
        ...
      
    }
    ...
}
```

Therefore make sure if they are the same. You should make adjustment with the folder structures as well if you made a change for the application id. Change the `example` folder name to `xxx`.

Comment: Note that since a while it is the `applicationId` defined in the app's `build.gradle` which determines the package name of the app (which distinguishes it on the store and as an app), and it does not have to be the same as the `android:package` attribute in the manifest. However, the latter should match the project's base package name as used for the source files. See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html.

Comment: @user905686 Thanks you so much for the new updates.